# VisualBasic: How do I authenticate with Kerberos using WinHTTP (or MSXML2)?

Tags: vba, kerberos

Szenario: Browser user is authenticated (single sign-on) on a Windows web server. On this server, a VisualBasic program should be accessing an application on another server with the current Kerberos credentials of the SSO user.

Question: How can I obtain a TGT ticket in VisualBasic (or pure Java) and extract the authorization token to be passed in the HTTP header "Authorization: Negotiate Yll..."?

Comment: If you need the header from a request that was set you can use getResponseHeader in MSXML2. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757006(v=vs.85)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a HTTP response header to pass along. I need to obtain a TGT ticket on the fly for the user wither thru an API or an REST call to the KDC.